# Users can't recover their password asp.net mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

As the title says my users can't recover their password if they lose it. For some reason it doesn't send the email. I have it working when they are going to confirm their email address than they do receives an email.

Here is the code for that:

```
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Username };
    user.Email = model.Email;
    user.EmailConfirmed = false;
    var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
    if (result.Succeeded)
    {
        MailMessage m = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress("noreply@stuff.net", "Web Registration"),
            new MailAddress(user.Email));
        m.Subject = "Email confirmation";
        m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Thank you for your registration, please click on the below link to complete your registration: <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Email Confirm\">{1}</a>", user.UserName, Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Token = user.Id, Email = user.Email }, Request.Url.Scheme));
        m.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.stuff.net");
        smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("noreply@stuff.net", "passwordstuff");
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        smtp.Port = 8889;
        smtp.Send(m);
        return RedirectToAction("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { Email = user.Email });
    }
    else
    {
        AddErrors(result);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for when they want to recover their password:

```
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
            if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
            {
                // Don't reveal that the user does not exist or is not confirmed
                return View("ForgotPasswordConfirmation");
            }

            string code = await UserManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

            MailMessage m = new MailMessage(
            new MailAddress("noreply@stuff.net", "Web Registration"),
            new MailAddress(user.Email));
            m.Subject = "Forgotten Password";
            m.Body = string.Format("Dear {0}<BR/>Please click on the below link to reset your password: <a href=\"{1}\" title=\"User Forgotten Password\">{1}</a>", user.UserName, Url.Action("ResetPassword", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme));
            m.IsBodyHtml = true;
            SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("mail.stuff.net");
            smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("noreply@stuff.net", "stuff");
            smtp.EnableSsl = false;
            smtp.Port = 8889;
            smtp.Send(m);
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotPasswordConfirmation", "Account");
        }
```

But for some reason this doesn't work, and they won't get an email on how to reset their password.

Comment: When you say "doesn't work", what do you mean? Is there an error? What is in your logs? Are you able to send e-mail manually using those credentials through your SMTP gateway?

Comment: Sorry, I was a bit unclear and I updated my post. The issue i'm facing is they do not get an email when they click Forgotten Password and enter their email. How ever they do get an email when they need to confirm their email.

Comment: Make sure your smtp settings are correct.

Comment: I can't specifically say why the second block of code doesn't work, but if the first one does, why not stick to what works? The second block of code you're not setting up any `NetworkCredential`, or specifying the port etc.

Comment: @DrewKennedy I did, I update my post now. I still can't get it to work as it should even if I use a similar thing like the first code block that works.

Comment: Give http://aboutcode.net/postal/ a look. It doesn't really have anything to do with your problem, but constructing email bodies in code harkens back to the days of spaghetti SQL. Sending emails utilizing strongly-typed views is a revelation.

Comment: @user2902364: First, you need to determine if the email is being sent at all. There may be a problem with your code, or it may be getting blocked by the receiving side, either completely or simply being sent to a spam folder.

Comment: @ChrisPratt You are correct, seems like it dosen't even jump in that code block. Which is more annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using MVC's out-of-the-box template, then:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByNameAsync(model.Email);
```

should really be:

```
var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(model.Email);
```

because the input box asks for email, not user name.

Then, unless you have set the site to require email confirmation, the line:

```
if (user == null || !(await UserManager.IsEmailConfirmedAsync(user.Id)))
```

should be

```
if (user == null)
```

This will at least get you to the codes that sends out the email.  I just ran into the same issue today, and the above changes solved it for me.